# Specify wait time between Actions when using Selenium Actionchains

Tags: python, selenium

The ActionChains is a very handy method when using Selenium. 
It works really well, only thing i am missing is how to insert wait times between the Actions.

I will take the same example from the official google Selenium Documentation.
https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/py/webdriver/selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.html

```
menu = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".nav")
hidden_submenu = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".nav #submenu1")

ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(menu).click(hidden_submenu).perform()
```

What i am looking for is a way to insert wait times between the two actions

```
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(menu)**(..wait some seconds)**.click(hidden_submenu).perform()
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### Note: Better answer

[RobZ's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48035805/3075814) is sufficient. The [`ActionChains` class has a `pause` method](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html?highlight=pause#selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.ActionChains.pause) that will do what was asked in the original question without requiring any subclassing or custom code.

#### Original answer

Here's a Python example based on Kim Homann's tip. It extends the `ActionChains` Selenium class to add a `wait` action.

```py
import time
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains

class Actions(ActionChains):
    def wait(self, time_s: float):
        self._actions.append(lambda: time.sleep(time_s))
        return self
```

Then your test becomes:

```py
Actions(driver) \
    .move_to_element(menu) \
    .wait(2) \
    .click(hidden_submenu) \
    .perform()
```

Comment: Updated with `pause` method, see [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48035805/10521959)

Answer (score 23):

I tried this and seems working

```
from selenium import webdriver 

action = webdriver.ActionChains(driver)

action.pause(3)

action.perform()

driver.close()
```

Comment: Here's the link: http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html?highlight=pause#selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.ActionChains.pause

Answer (score 5):

I don't know Python, but I think it's the same as in C#. I hope my code is readable for you.

You can create your own class `ActionsEx` deriving from `Actions`. Then you declare a method `public Actions Wait(TimeSpan duration)`. Inside this method, you call `AddAction(new SleepAction(duration));`. `AddAction()` is a protected method of Selenium's `Actions` class, which is accessible only if you derive from this class.

`SleepAction` is a class implementing the `IAction` interface, which you have to create. It can look like this example:

```
public class SleepAction : IAction
{
    public SleepAction(TimeSpan duration)
    {
        _duration = duration;
    }

    private TimeSpan _duration;

    void IAction.Perform()
    {
        ToolBox.Sleep((int) _duration.TotalMilliseconds);
    }
}
```

**ActionsEx class:**

```
public class ActionsEx : Actions
{
    public ActionsEx(IWebDriver driver) : base(driver)
    {
    }

    public Actions Wait(TimeSpan duration)
    {
        AddAction(new SleepAction(duration));

        return this;
    }
}
```

Then you can call an action chain like this:

```
var actions = new ActionsEx(driver);
var duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);

((ActionsEx)actions
    .Wait(duration)
    .MoveToElement(element))
    .Wait(duration)
    .Click()
    .Build()
    .Perform();
```

Comment: What library should we import to be able to use ToolBox.Sleep method  ?

Comment: The ToolBox is just something from my personal code. You can call whatever sleep method you like, usually System.Threading.Thread.Sleep()

Comment: Seems that `AddAction` was removed in WebDriver 4.0+.

Comment: Maybe extension methods would be appropriate in this context:


`private static Actions Wait(this Actions actions, int delay)
{
    Task.Delay(delay).Wait(); // Not async!
    return actions;
}`


And incorporating it into the Action chain like this:


`var actions = new Actions(acc.Wb.Driver);

            actions.MoveToElement(element)
                .Wait(5)
                .Build()
                .Perform();`

Answer (score 2):

Simply import the time modul and use sleep whenever you need it:

```
from time import sleep

action = webdriver.ActionChains(driver)
action.move_to_element(menu)
sleep(5)
action.click(hidden_submenu).perform()
```

Hope this helps you a bit.

Comment: If i execute that, then it won't be a chain anymore. They will be separate Actions. For example if i want to click on a menu item and then wait a bit and then press Down and then press Enter, these three Actions should be executed as a chain.

Comment: check my edit, should also work like this, but I never tested

Comment: ActionChains hat no attribute sleep :)

Comment: This Problem is only specific to the Website I am testing. The first Suggestion works fine on other Websites i just checked-

Comment: @midopa answer below is one that should be accepted

Answer (score 2):

I believe the issue is that a delay executed outside of the `ActionChain` will be ignored once `perform` is called. Think of the chain like a queue of actions in `sched`: you could wait for hours and hours between *adding* items to the queue, but once you call `run`, each task will execute in simple sequence without a delay.

So, to create a delay **inside** the chain, I would use Selenium's `pause` method.

Docs here: http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html